# How to create a shared Service (as Angular ones) but in vanilla Typescript Nativescript

Tags: typescript, service, nativescript, shared

i am used in Angular and Nativescript. I would like to try Typescript only template for nativescript (tns create myApp --template tsc)... but i need to have a shared Service as i would in Angular... can this be done in Vanilla typescript Nativescript ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If you have used Angular you must be aware of dependency injection, which is nothing but wisely create instances and reuse them as needed.

So in short, all you have to do is create your instance of your class and reuse it every time. For example,

```
class Service {
  ...
}

let instance;
export function getService() {
  if (!instance) {
     instance = new Service ();
  }
  return instance;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use the singleton pattern. In TypeScript it would look like this.

```
export class SharedService {
  static instance = null;

  constructor() {
      if (SharedService.instance !== null) {
         return SharedService.instance;
      } else {
         SharedService.instance = this;
      }
  }
}
```

This would create the instance only the first time, then it will reuse the first for any other call. So even if you do 200 calls to `new SharedService()`, you'll always have only one instance in your app.